# Internet access on android virtual device

Tags: android, uri, internet-connection

I have a problem with android virtual device.
I am trying to download some JSON from the internet and try some ways like using apache httpcommons and standart URIConnection.
The app always crashes without any notification in Android Studio. I added the permissions in the manifest (INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE) and checked the connection like in the android guideline:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
boolean internet = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable();
```

and if I try to get the ip address from URI, it crashes too:

```
try {
    InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("google.com");
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Who knows how I can get access to internet from a virtual device?

p.s. unfortunately I don't have a real device to test on.

upd. when i use debug i see what i stopped in

```
performLaunchActivity()
```

Comment: Did you try to load a web page using web browser in emulator?

Comment: yes, i can easy access from std browser in AVDevice

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: no proxy. dirrect connection to internet

Comment: Are you sure that getActiveNetworkInfo() is succeeding?  It may be returning null, which would cause an exception when you try to call isAvailable().

Comment: yes. i write this

<code>NetworkInfo.State ss =  cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().getState();</code>

and in debug mode i see state "Connected"

Comment: Ok.  In your example when you print the stack trace, what's there?  Please copy and paste the whole trace into your question.

Comment: trouble in my mind.

I try to use network in UI thread - this is problem. When i use AsyncTask or Threan whith Runnable - all great work. 

Thx all for help.